# Custom page view design in scroll view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

#### My Goal

Basically, I want to implement something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyhczdflub0dyr0/map.gif?dl=0): A view that slides to each page at the bottom of screen.

#### My Background

I'm getting familiar with swift and storyboard, but not knowing much about objective-c or nib(xib)

#### My Attempts

- At the beginning, I got to know that enabling PagingMode of UIScrollView could satisfy my needs. Then I checked the *Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS: Scrolling Using Paging Mode* provided by Apple. The *PageControl* example is pretty close, but it uses nib files and I don't really know how to customise that.
- I also found a tutorial of [UIPageViewController], but I don't know if it can be resize to bottom of my screen.
- I searched for various until I found [*UIScrollView Tutorial: Getting Started*](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift). It covers a lot and is written in swift, but it still puts just an imageView as a contentView inside the scrollView.

#### My Questions

1. How to make a custom view of one page, acts as a template for each page data in storyboard and all those link stuff? (If it is better to use nib files, references are appreciated)
2. How to do auto layout with scrollview to satisfy

   - the scroll view takes only the bottom part of screen
   - the labels, buttons inside content view (one page) layout properly
3. If there're easier or better ways to accomplish my goal, please please tell me!

**Note** Sorry for no more than 2 links due to lacking of reputations

Answer (score 0):

I can answer #2:

Make sure you `scrollView` is selected. Now, go to **editor**->**pin**->**Leading space to superView**.

Repeat that for **Bottom space to superview** and **trailing space to superView**.

Next, **ctrl+drag** from the `scrollView` to the superview itself. Pick **equal widths**.

Finally, select the constraint by left clicking it from the storyboard, or selecting the `scrollView` and selecting it from the size inspector.

Change the **constant** value of the constraint to **0**. Change the multiplier to **0.5**. Make sure the **first item** is scrollView, and if not, click the drop down box and **reverse first and second item**.

That will give you the `scrollView` you want: 0.5 times the height of the superView (half of the screen).

Comment: I wonder if you missed the constraints for height. Do you mean changing the value to 0 and the multiplier to 0.5 is applied only to the height constraints or all of the leading, bottom, trailing and equal widths?

Comment: I was referring only for the equal widths constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection view with custom flow layout
you can refer this one and make changes in [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout).

This is my customization:

[image: customflowlayout collection view]